# How to integrate wordpress blog to php website blog page with site header and footer design?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, integration

I want to display wordpress blog to my php website's blog page without using  and header and footer will be same like my site design but only in content part i want to display blog posts of wordpress blog.. then how it possible?? Please guide me for this..

Comment: Refer to the template hierarchy section in wordpress.

Comment: I am having doubt here if you mean "with" or "without":
"without using and header and footer ".
Or in the other words, you are asking to apply a custom design to your blog in wordpress?

Comment: If you can build WP theme in according to entire site's design and integrate with WP.

Comment: Exactly i want wordpress blog content part which contains blog posts that i want to display in my blog page ..

Answer (score 0):

You should create a template in wordpress without header and footer. Then get this page using i frame from your php site.

Or you can create a webservice for these blog data from wordpress site and get this from your php site.

Comment: You are right but if i will use iframe then it will be complicated because if any user go to perticular blog post then url will be same so for SEO purpose it will not work.. so i have mentioned in my quesion that i want another way without making any use of <iframe>.. your answer is really appreciated.. thank you Ryan.

Answer (score 0):

I used this article to pull my blog posts onto my normal website.

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/display-posts-on-external-website

1) Here’s the code you will want to write in BEFORE the Doctype (so the very first of your HTML):

```
<?php
//db parameters
$db_username = '###';
$db_password = '###';
$db_database = '###';

$blog_url = 'http://www.jamischarles.com/blog/'; //base folder for the blog.       Make SURE there is a slash at the end

//connect to the database
mysql_connect(localhost, $db_username, $db_password);
@mysql_select_db($db_database) or die("Unable to select database");

//get data from database -- !IMPORTANT, the "LIMIT 5" means how many posts 
$query = "Select * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type='post' AND        post_status='publish' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5"; 

$query_result = mysql_query($query);
$num_rows = mysql_numrows($query_result);

//close database connection
mysql_close();

// html page starts after ?>
?>
< !DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
<head>
</head>
```

2) Now, the text in the body will be a little bit different. Continuing where we left off…
Now, the problem here, is that we have dynamically generated content. That means we write a loop that goes through each table row in the database, gets the title, date, and text, then spits out on the html, and goes to the next row of the database and does the same thing again.

So if we use a div with same id, it’ll show that div up 5 times, each time with a different post. This is not acceptable, because it is not valid code, and could mess up the CSS. So we have to give it a class to be valid, or use tables. For this example we’ll use divs.

```
<body>

<?php

//start a loop that starts $i at 0, and make increase until it's at the   number of rows
for($i=0; $i< $num_rows; $i++){ 

//assign data to variables, $i is the row number, which increases with each    run of the loop
$blog_date = mysql_result($query_result, $i, "post_date");
$blog_title = mysql_result($query_result, $i, "post_title");
$blog_content = mysql_result($query_result, $i, "post_content");
//$blog_permalink = mysql_result($query_result, $i, "guid"); //use this line for p=11 format.

$blog_permalink = $blog_url . mysql_result($query_result, $i, "post_name");       //combine blog url, with permalink title. Use this for title format

//format date
$blog_date = strtotime($blog_date);
$blog_date = strftime("%b %e", $blog_date);

//the following HTML content will be generated on the page as many times as   the loop runs. In this case 5.
?>

</body>
<div class="post"></div>

<span class="date">  <?php echo $blog_date; ?>:</code></span><br /><hr   /> 

<a href="http://www.bluebreeze.net/blog"><?php echo $blog_title; ?></a>      <br /><br />

<?php echo $blog_content; ?> <br /><br />

<a href=”<?php echo $blog_permalink; ?>”>This Article</a> <br />
<a href="http://www.bluebreeze.net/blog">More Articles </a>
<?php
} //end the for loop
?>
```

Comment: No problem! choose as answer if its the one you go for - thanks